# Why can't I use Image.open on PIL files?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, jpeg, huggingface-datasets

I have written a simple code to download an audio dataset from ccmusic on hugging face. Problem is that somehow I can't open PIL images from said dataset with Image.Open() ... Can somebody explain why that is? And how to fix it?

If I run my code:

```
import datasets
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from datasets import load_dataset

dataset = load_dataset("ccmusic-database/music_genre", split="test")
output = dataset
im = Image.open(output[0])
im.show()
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/abc/Desktop/Project Python Audio/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 3247, in open
> fp.seek(0)
> ^^^^^^^
> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'seek'
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/abc/Desktop/Project Python Audio/loading_dataset.py", line 8, in 
> im = Image.open(output[0])
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/Users/abc/Desktop/Project Python Audio/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 3249, in open
> fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
> ^^^^^^^
> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'read'

However, if I print the file with:

```
import datasets
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from datasets import load_dataset

dataset = load_dataset("ccmusic-database/music_genre", split="test")
output = dataset
print(output[0])
```

I get:

> {'image': <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=476x349 at 0x101BE6E10>, 'fst_level_label': 1, 'sec_level_label': 6, 'thr_level_label': 6, 'duration': 416.0533106575964}

So it seems the PIL / Jpeg file array is located at the right position at output[0] ... but Image.open is unable to display it ... what is going on here and how can I watch the image?

Comment: `PIL.Image.open` creates an image object from a file. But looks like you already have an image object which you can access as `im=output[0]['image']`.

Comment: You are absolutely right. im=output[0]['image'] works fine. I did not know that one can put the output array directly into the  im-equation. Thank you for your fast answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the `type` of `dataset[0]` you will see it is a `dict`:

```
print(type(dataset[0]]
dict
```

If you print it:

```
print(dataset[0])
{'image': <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=476x349 at 0x101BE6E10>,
'fst_level_label': 1,
'sec_level_label': 6,
'thr_level_label': 6,
'duration': 416.0533106575964}
```

you can see it is a `dict` because it is in curly braces. The *"keys"* are given in the left column and the corresponding *"values"* are on the right.

That means if you access `dataset[0]["image"]` the object you are looking at is already a `PIL Image` so you can copy it and use it exactly the same as if you'd created it with `Image.open()`.

Answer (score 1):

Got the code working (see below) thanks to @slothrop

```
import datasets
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from datasets import load_dataset

dataset = load_dataset("ccmusic-database/music_genre", split="test")
output = dataset
im = output[0]['image']
im.show()
```